# Powervault: MD1200 EMMs in an MD3200 enclosure?

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc

I have two MD1200 EMMs (Dell part #3DJRJ). Can I use them in an MD3200 enclosure (which is available at an economical price than an MD1200 enclosure).

If it would work, would I lose any functionality? This will be connected to a poweredge R910 using an H810 controller card.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion on [Are Dell PowerVault MD3200 EMMs compatible with the MD1200 chassis/midplane?](https://serverfault.com/questions/715612/are-dell-powervault-md3200-emms-compatible-with-the-md1200-chassis-midplane), please keep in mind that such configurations are almost untested, therefore an  supported configuration and may have unwanted side-effects.

Of course, you would loose all the firmware features and intelligence from the MD3200, since MD1200 is Just a Bunch Of Disks (JBOD).

After [tests of some users](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerVault/Convert-MD3200i-to-MD1200/td-p/6061759) it seems that

> the backplane [firmware] that is preventing the MD1200 EMM from working.

So you may need a MD1200 backplane too.